# Why does a nested self-capturing function interfere with isKnownUniquelyReferenced(_:)?

Tags: swift

I was attempting to implement copy-on-write behaviour in a custom collection when I came across this strange behaviour with nested functions that capture `self`.

In the following code, the call to [`isKnownUniquelyReferenced(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2429905-isknownuniquelyreferenced) will always return false, despite being called *before* the nested function is even defined:

```
class Foo {}

struct Bar {

    var foo = Foo()

    public mutating func bar() {

        print(isKnownUniquelyReferenced(&foo))

        func nestedFunc() {
            _ = self // capture self
        }
        nestedFunc()
    }
}

var b = Bar()
b.bar() // false ?!
```

Why on earth is this the case, and what can I do to fix it (assuming that `nestedFunc` actually does something useful with `self`)?

I’m aware that the capturing of `self` could interfere with the call to `isKnownUniquelyReferenced(_:)` – but surely that happens at the point of calling `nestedFunc()` in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Swift 3.1 Update

As of Swift 3.1, available with Xcode 8.3 beta, this has been fixed. `self` is no longer boxed at all in the method, therefore `isKnownUniquelyReferenced(_:)` returns `true` as expected.

---

#### Pre Swift 3.1

I consider this a bug, and have filed a bug report ([SR-3530](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3530)). I was however interested by the cause of this problem, so did some digging – and this is what I found.

Taking a look at the canonical SIL generated for the `bar()` method (for an -Onone build) reveals that Swift is heap allocating a box ([`alloc_box`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst#alloc-box)) for `self` at the *very beginning* of the method – so that it can be captured by `nestedFunc()`.

```
// Bar.bar() -> ()
sil hidden @main.Bar.bar () -> () : $@convention(method) (@inout Bar) -> () {
// %0                                             // users: %10, %3
bb0(%0 : $*Bar):

  // create new heap-allocated box, and store self in it.
  // this is where the problem stems from – there are now two copies of the Bar instance, thus isKnownUniquelyReferenced will return false.
  %1 = alloc_box $Bar, var, name "self", argno 1, loc "main.swift":15:26, scope 9 // users: %11, %9, %7, %2
  %2 = project_box %1 : $@box Bar, loc "main.swift":15:26, scope 9 // users: %10, %5, %3
  copy_addr %0 to [initialization] %2 : $*Bar, scope 9 // id: %3

  // call isKnownUniquelyReferenced (I removed the print() function call as it generates a bunch of unrelated SIL).
  // function_ref isKnownUniquelyReferenced<A where ...> (inout A) -> Bool
  %4 = function_ref @Swift.isKnownUniquelyReferenced <A where A: Swift.AnyObject> (inout A) -> Swift.Bool : $@convention(thin) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : AnyObject> (@inout τ_0_0) -> Bool, loc "main.swift":17:9, scope 10 // user: %6
  %5 = struct_element_addr %2 : $*Bar, #Bar.foo, loc "main.swift":17:35, scope 10 // user: %6
  %6 = apply %4<Foo>(%5) : $@convention(thin) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : AnyObject> (@inout τ_0_0) -> Bool, loc "main.swift":17:39, scope 10

  // retain the heap-allocated box containing self, in preparation for applying nestedFunc() with it.
  // (as it's passed as an @owned parameter).
  strong_retain %1 : $@box Bar, loc "main.swift":27:9, scope 10 // id: %7

  // call the nested function with the box as the argument.
  // function_ref Bar.(bar() -> ()).(nestedFunc #1)() -> ()
  %8 = function_ref @main.Bar.(bar () -> ()).(nestedFunc #1) () -> () : $@convention(thin) (@owned @box Bar) -> (), loc "main.swift":27:9, scope 10 // user: %9
  %9 = apply %8(%1) : $@convention(thin) (@owned @box Bar) -> (), loc "main.swift":27:20, scope 10

  // once called, copy the contents of the box back to the address of the Bar instance that was passed into the method, and release the box.
  copy_addr %2 to %0 : $*Bar, scope 10            // id: %10
  strong_release %1 : $@box Bar, loc "main.swift":29:5, scope 10 // id: %11

  // so cute.
  %12 = tuple (), loc "main.swift":29:5, scope 10 // user: %13
  return %12 : $(), loc "main.swift":29:5, scope 10 // id: %13
}
```

<sup>([Full SIL here](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/6188acb60ddf9787fa66f4b5c5df32f6))</sup>

Because of this boxing, there are now *two* copies of the `Bar` instance in the `bar()` method, therefore meaning that `isKnownUniquelyReferenced(_:)` will return false, as there are two references to the `Foo` instance.

From what I can tell, the boxing of `self` at the beginning of the method seems to be a consequence of the optimisation of the `mutating` method from copy-in copy-out (`self` gets boxed at the start of the method call, mutations are then applied to that box, then written back to the callee at the end of the method) to pass-by-reference (this optimisation occurs between the raw SIL and canonical SIL).

The same box that was used in order to create a copy of `self` to mutate within the method is *now* used in order to capture `self` to call the nested function with. I see no reason why the box for the capture shouldn’t be created just before the call to `nestedFunc()`, as that’s the logical place to capture `self` (rather than at the beginning of the method).

Although, in any case, the creation of a box is completely redundant in the first place, as `nestedFunc()` doesn’t and *cannot* escape. Attempting to return `nestedFunc()` from the method yields the following compiler error:

> Nested function cannot capture inout parameter and escape

So it really just looks like a corner case that hasn’t been optimised yet. Even in an -O build, although the heap allocation for the `Bar` instance is able to be optimised to a stack allocation for just the `foo` property, this still results in an unnecessary second reference to the `Foo` instance.

---

#### Solutions

One solution would be to just add an `inout` `self` parameter to `nestedFunc()`, allowing `self` to just be passed by reference, rather than being captured:

```
func nestedFunc(_ `self`: inout Bar) {
    _ = self // do something useful with self
}
// ...
nestedFunc(&self)
```

which now generates the SIL (-Onone):

```
// function_ref Bar.(bar() -> ()).(nestedFunc #1)(inout Bar) -> ()
%5 = function_ref @main.Bar.(bar () -> ()).(nestedFunc #1) (inout main.Bar) -> () : $@convention(thin) (@inout Bar) -> (), loc "main.swift":31:9, scope 10 // user: %6
%6 = apply %5(%0) : $@convention(thin) (@inout Bar) -> (), loc "main.swift":31:25, scope 10
```

The advantage of this solution is that it's just a straightforward pass-by-reference (as the `Bar` parameter is marked [`@inout`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst#inout-arguments)). Because of this, there only ever exists one copy of the instance of `Bar` – thus `isKnownUniquelyReferenced(_:)` can return true.

Another possible solution, if `self` isn’t mutated within `nestedFunc()`, is to pass `self` by *value*, rather than reference. This can be done with a capture list in a local closure:

```
let nestedFunc = { [`self` = self] in // copy self into the closure.
    _ = self                          // the self inside the closure is immutable.
}
// ...
nestedFunc()
```

The advantage is that you don’t need to explicitly pass anything into the `nestedFunc()` call. Because the instance of `Bar` isn’t passed by value until the closure creation – it won’t interfere with the call to `isKnownUniquelyReferenced(_:)`, assuming that the call precedes the closure creation.